# c++ inheritance design issue

Tags: c++, polymorphism, abstract-class, pure-virtual

In c++ I  want to have an array of the abstract type Query which has the function calcScore()
which is a pure virtual function.
And I have two classes which are non-abstract: ConQuery and DisQuery that implements the calcScore function.

In order to do I defined the array like this:

```
vector<Query*> m;
```

and I iterate and call the function like this:

```
for (vector<Query*>::const_iterator it1 = index.begin() ;it1 != index.end() ; it1++)
{
     cout << (*it1)->CalcScore() << endl; 
}
```

I get an error for **calling a pure virtual function** of Query.
How do I make it call to the function of ConQuery or the one of DisQuery by the polymorphic type?
thanks.

Comment: How do you initialize that `vector`?

Comment: `vector<Query*> m;` but then `vector<Query>::const_iterator`... what is the **real** type of the container? At any rate, the error indicates that you are calling a virtual function of `Query` from the constructor/destructor of `Query`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure CalcScore is implemented in ConQuery and DisQuery ?
I tried this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Query{
public:
    virtual int CalcScore() = 0;
};

class Query2 : public Query
{
public:
    virtual int CalcScore()
    {

        return 2;
    }
};

class Query3 : public Query
{
public:
    virtual int CalcScore()
    {

        return 3;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    std::vector<Query*> m;
    m.push_back(new Query2());
        m.push_back(new Query3());
    for (std::vector<Query*>::const_iterator it1 =  m.begin() ;it1 !=  m.end() ; it1++)
    {
        std::cout  << (*it1)->CalcScore();
    }
}
```

and it works fine under my VS2012.

Also I used it tons of times in some of my projects.

Maybe you try to push_back a Query item ( and not a con/dis ) ?

Comment: The compiler should flag if you attempt to create a `Query` value, as you cannot create an object of an abstract type...

Comment: Isn't it a compiler issue he is having anyways?

Comment: The compiler does not allow you to create an instance of an abstract class, which means that it would fail *before* you have an instance on which to call a pure virtual function.

Answer (score 3):

The error can only occur in the language if you try to call a pure virtual function from the constructor or destructor of the type (where the most derived type is not yet built/has already been destroyed):

```
struct Query {
   virtual void f() = 0;
   Query() {
      f();                // !!
   }
   ~Query() {
      f();                // !!
   }
};
```

Note that compilers usually flag the code above as an error, but will fail to detect it if the call is not *directly* in the constructor/destructor, if for example you pass a reference to the object to a different function that performs the call.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for (vector<Query>::const_iterator it1 = index.begin() ;it1 != index.end() ; it1++)
```

to

```
for (vector<Query *>::const_iterator it1 = index.begin() ;it1 != index.end() ; it1++)
```

Comment: The * was there, forgot to write it here.

Answer (score 1):

I might have missed something but this works for me:
I already know that i is not initialised etc ;-)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>


class Query
{
public:
    int i;
    void virtual CalcScore() = 0;
};

class ConQuery :public Query
{
public:
    int i;
    void virtual CalcScore() {i++;}

};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<Query*> index;
    ConQuery b;

    index.push_back(&b);

    for (std::vector<Query*>::const_iterator it1 = index.begin() ;it1 != index.end() ; it1++) 
    {      
        (*it1)->CalcScore();
    } 

    return 0;
}
```